# Camera world matrix to view matrix

Tags: mathematics, camera, matrix, transformation

I've been working on a game engine and I model every object in my scene graph as an "entity" this includes my camera.

My camera therefore has a position and rotation in world space and at the moment I am able to create a view matrix by taking the inverse of the cameras world space matrix.

However when I do this the camera looks in the opposite direction to what I would expect.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 2):

I actually think everything is okay! All I needed to clarify in my system is which direction is forwards, and I picked -z and that seems to have fixed my confusion.

So it wasn't that my camera was facing the wrong direction, it was everything else that was facing the wrong direction!

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: lol good to hear you fixed your problem :)